# Remove all text from a specific tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear all list items in my `<body>`. So on a button press, the item text from all the lists are removed. No use of IDs or anything, just if there is an `<li>` tag, it's `innerHTML` is cleared out.

I have tried a few different methods, but I cannot figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Basically what I was trying to do is clearly incorrect as you can see here:

```
function clearLI() {
    document.getElementById("li").innerHTML = ""
};
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => li.remove())` or if you want to keep the elements in the DOM then `.textContent = ''`

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you so much!

Comment: Use jQuery: $('button').click(function(){ $('li').html('') });

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply by iterating over every `li` element and settings its `innerHTML` to nil.

Here's the code.

`Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li')).forEach(el => el.innerHTML = '');`

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
innerHTML.replace(newValue);
```

?
Or did you forget to hyperlink Li to body?